# How to decrease query execution time with DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-performance

I have slow query:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ON ( topic_category_id ) * FROM topic t
    WHERE abstime ( post_time + 24 * 3600 ) >= now ( )
    ORDER BY topic_category_id, post_time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

It's because I use DISTINCT but I can find out how I can change this query. I can't use GROUP BY because I need to be ordered by post_time. Please advise

Comment: can you pre-compute a column with abstime ( post_time + 24 * 3600 ) ? so you could try an index on it

Comment: Which Postgres version do you use? `abstime` is a deprecated internal datetime type. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I have already index on post_time column. And I have PostgreSql 8.4.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ON ( topic_category_id ) * FROM (SELECT *FROM topic t
    WHERE abstime ( post_time + 24 * 3600 ) >= now ( )
    ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 500) tmp ORDER BY topic_category_id limit 10;
This query is fast (http://explain.depesz.com/s/MEf), but it has problem with limit, when I tried remove LIMIT 500 and query becomes slow (http://explain.depesz.com/s/j6g4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be worth a try:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ON ( topic_category_id ) * FROM topic t
    WHERE post_time >= abstime(now ( ) - 24 * 3600 )
    ORDER BY topic_category_id, post_time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The reason it might be faster is that Postgres can do the time calc only once, rather than do the calc for each row returned.